# File with links growing huge, even without edits

Tags: blend-files, linked-data

In my last few blender sessions editing a file with two linked character files (151M and 55M respectively), my resulting saved file size is blooming out of control (now at 525).

[image]

My last save was to read in a saved file*TMP version and saveAs file with no edits or changes -- grew from 317M to 525M that now takes minutes to load even though RAM is at about 50% and barely growing.  It would almost seem like the links in my file became Local, plus copies of each in 3 scenes.  Any thoughts on what might be causing this and how to investigate/prevent?  I have been mostly making changes to my animation, and one mesh's property that allows a library override.

[image]

I don't see any mesh overrides that could be the problem.

[image]

My workaround has been to take the older, smaller file, Append my action changes from the immense file, and it saves as a reasonable 83M file.   However this is happening every couple of days now with this setup.

BTW, my 525M file is now at 1G, having only opened it?!?  blender v3.1.

Comment: Maybe it's a blender bug? Did you try switching to the previous/latest version of Blender? Or maybe try taking a new file altogether and copy>paste everything there?

Comment: @ChaudhryYousuf -- yes recovering from a new/older file works, but I don't want that daily chore that can be error prone and having to verify all's well in three separate scenes.

Comment: So did you try upgrading/downgrading the blender version? Maybe it's a bug in the current version?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a script that will rebuild the blend file including multiple scenes.  When saved the size is back to something sane.   Open this script in a blank blender file, set your file name (decrepit, i know), and run.

```
import bpy

d1=bpy.data
fileName1=bpy.context.blend_data.filepath

def AppendAllInFile( filename ):
    sceneNames = []
    with bpy.data.libraries.load( filename, link=False) as (data_src, data_dst):
        data_dst.scenes = data_src.scenes
        print( 'data_src',data_src )
        print( 'data_dst',data_dst )
        for scene in data_src.scenes:
            sceneNames.append({'name': scene})
            print('scene',scene)
    
    bpy.ops.wm.append(directory=filename+"/Scene/", files=sceneNames)

fileName1='C:\\Users\\...\\bones\\LargeFile.blend'
AppendAllInFile( fileName1 )
```